# Assigning variables in SQL Query c#

Tags: asp.net, sql, razor, prepared-statement

How do i assign variable cats so that it pulls the rows in database which we specify in cat variable ? I did query like below but doesn't work. Thanks

```
var cats = "white";
var selectCommand = "SELECT TOP(10) * FROM mytable WHERE parent = @cats";
```

Comment: Show your code that actually executes the command. What data access technology are you using? Razor is not a data access tech, it's a language for writing Views.

Comment: var selectCommand = "SELECT TOP(10) * FROM mytable WHERE parent = "+cats;

Comment: @MSUH That statement would break, since cats is a string in this case.

Comment: @MSUH http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you expect something like this

```
var selectCommand = "SELECT TOP(10) * FROM mytable WHERE parent = @cats";
var cmd= new SqlCommand(selectCommand, yourconnetion);

cmd.Parameters["@cats"].Value = "white";
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cats","white");
```

Comment: If you remove the `"` from the SqlCommand it would work, otherwise the query would be `"selectCommand"` instead of the SQL in `selectCommand`

Comment: Smart with the Parameters-property, I had forgot about that actually. :)